# Trying to replicate a visualisation in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Relatively inexperienced R user. I am trying to create something similar to the visualisation below with data for another country.  [image]

I've gone as far as creating the basic structure with data plotted in a vertical annual timeline with months running along the x axis but I have no idea how to edit the individual data points. I would appreciate any idea on how to move forward or even a completely different approach.

Here is my code using ggplot2:

```
p <- ggplot(forestfiresv, aes(y=year, x=dtstart))
p+geom_point() + 
  scale_x_datetime(lim=as.POSIXct(c("2021-01-01 00:01","2021-12-31 00:00", origin=lubridate::origin), "%m/%d %H:%M",tz="UTC"),expand = c(0,0), date_breaks="2 months", labels = date_format("%b"))+
  theme_bw()
```

A data sample:

```
structure(list(year = c("2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", 
"2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2000"), `Start date` = structure(c(11174, 11167, 11166, 11191, 
11222, 11144, 11151, 11192, 11244, 11187), class = "Date"), `Start time` = c("02:15", 
"16:05", "10:47", "15:41", "23:30", "15:29", "14:00", "13:53", 
"17:39", "11:09"), `End date` = structure(c(11174, 
11178, 11166, 11192, 11223, 11146, 11152, 11197, 11244, 11191
), class = "Date"), `End time` = c("14:00", "07:00", "19:00", 
"22:00", "02:00", "12:00", "00:10", "13:30", "19:07", "11:30"
), Δάση = c(200, 1400, 400, 0, 0, 0, 600, 2000, 0, 260), `Forest` = c(800, 
0, 0, 100, 100, 700, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Agricultural land` = c(0, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, 200, 500, 0, 0), totalareaburnt = c(1000, 1400, 400, 500, 500, 700,    800, 2500, 350, 360), dtstart = structure(c(1628129700, 1627574700,    1627469220, 1629646860, 1632353400, 1625585340, 1626184800, 1629726780, 1634233140, 1629284940), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), dtend = structure(c(1628172000, 1628492400, 1627498800, 1629756000, 1632362400, 1625745600, 1626221400, 1630157400, 1634238420, 1629631800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .internal.selfref = <pointer: (nil)>, row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: please can you share a sample of your data in a usable format, such as with `dput(forestfiresv)`, or if the data are too big `dput(head(forestfiresv,10))`

Comment: I edited above to include the dput output.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best  I've obtained so far, but I bet it could be better. I've increased your example data frame because there was only one year of observation and I've injected some randomness to make the plot look better.

```
library(ggplot2)

ddf <- rbind(df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df,df)
ddf$year <- rep(2000:2009,each=10)
ddf$totalareaburnt <- sample(200:2500,100,replace = T)
ddf$dtstart <- ddf$dtstart+sample(86400*1:90,100,replace = T)
#duration in days
ddf$duration <- as.numeric(df$dtend-df$dtstart)/24
ddf$year <- as.integer(ddf$year)

ggplot(ddf,
       aes(y = year,
           x = dtstart)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = totalareaburnt,
                 col = duration), 
             shape = 17,
             alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_x_datetime(
    lim = as.POSIXct(
      c("2021-01-01 00:01", "2021-12-31 00:00", origin = lubridate::origin),
      "%m/%d %H:%M",
      tz = "UTC"
    ),
    expand = c(0, 0),
    date_breaks = "1 months",
    labels = scales::date_format("%b")
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(),
    axis.ticks = element_line()
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", breaks = unique(ddf$year))+
  scale_colour_gradientn(name= "Duartion (day)",colours = c( "yellow", "orange","darkred"))+
  scale_size_continuous(name="Area burned (ha)")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this! do you know if there is a way to adapt only the height of the shape to 'totalareaburnt' and not the whole size?

Comment: I've searched for this but did not find anything.